# Execute Method on ClassSyntaxDefinition Source Generator

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

I'm trying to write a source generator.

My plan is to allow my users to create a class with `[GenerateMySource]` attribute and implement `IGenerateMySource` which has a `static abstract void Define()` method on it returning a `SourceDefinition` object.

For every class that has this attribute in my code, I want to generate some source based upon the return value of the `.Define()` method.

I can find the relevant `ClassDefinitionSyntax` nodes with this `ISyntaxReceiver` (not tested it yet but it should be about right):

```cs
public class MySyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
{
    public List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> ApiDefinitions = new();

    public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
    {
        if (syntaxNode is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
        {
            foreach (var attributeList in classDeclaration.AttributeLists)
            {
                foreach (var attribute in attributeList.Attributes)
                {
                    if (attribute.Name.ToString() == nameof(GenerateMySourceAttribute))
                    {
                        ApiDefinitions.Add(classDeclaration);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my actual source generator I want to be able to call the `.Define()` method on it. Then use that to generate my source:

```
[Generator]
public class MySourceGenerator: ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new MySyntaxReceiver());
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var receiver = (MySyntaxReceiver)context.SyntaxReceiver;
        
        foreach (var apiDefinition in receiver.ApiDefinitions)
        {
            SourceDefinition definition = apiDefinition.UnderlyingType.Define(); // This .UnderlyingType is made up

            // Do some stuff with the definition
            context.AddSource(name, source);
        }        
    }
}
```

Is this even possible? If so, how would I do it?

---

Edit: I figured the only way to do this is going to be to compile the relevant syntax tree into memory and then call it.

So I've tried this:

```cs
    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var receiver = (MySyntaxReceiver)context.SyntaxReceiver;

        foreach (var apiDefinition in receiver.ApiDefinitions)
        {
            List<MetadataReference> references = new();
            references.AddRange(context.Compilation.ExternalReferences);
            references.AddRange(context.Compilation.References);

            CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("test.dll",
                                                                     new[] {apiDefinition.SyntaxTree},
                                                                     references,
                                                                     new(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
                                                                    );

            using MemoryStream memStream = new();
            var                res       = compilation.Emit(memStream);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Assembly           ass       = Assembly.Load(memStream.ToArray());
            // Find my type and reflectively call the method
        }
    }
```

However, despite `res` reporting a successful compilation, `ass.GetTypes()` reports a `System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException` exception.

I've also tried emitting to file and reading it back in gives me the same problem. Yet, when I read the .dll file with dotpeek, all looks good! I'm guessing that there's some dependencies not getting resolved when I try to read it back...

[image]

Comment: any update @ScottishTapWater? facing the same problem here

Comment: @leandromoh - I decided it wasn't practicable and  just defined the bits I needed in yaml instead and parse that in my source gen. If you work it out though, let me know